# setTimeout callback function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling a function using onClick inside button. The called function is inside an object and it is getting called each second using setTimeout. But callback function is not getting called by setTimeout and works for just first call.

if i do not use object and use a encapsulating function that returns startPomadoro function, then its working.

```
     ###HTML Code ##########

<div class="cold-md-12 text-center">
            <button>Set Pomodoro</button>
             <input id="pomodoroInput" type="number">
            <button>Set Break</button>
             <input id="breakInput" type="number">
        </div>
        <div class="cold-md-12 text-center"><br>
            <button onClick="pomodoroClock.startPomodoro()">Start Pomodoro</button>

        </div>
        <div id="output">

        </div>
### JS COde

var pomodoroClock = {
    countPomadoro: 0,
    countBreak: 0,
    currentTimerText:'',

    startPomodoro: function(){
        var pomadoroTimeInMinutes = document.getElementById('pomodoroInput').value;
        var breakInMinutes = document.getElementById('breakInput').value;
        if(this.countPomadoro<pomadoroTimeInMinutes){
            var minutesLeftPomadoro = pomadoroTimeInMinutes - this.countPomadoro;
            this.currentTimerText = "Your have " + minutesLeftPomadoro + " Minutes Left.";
            this.countPomadoro++;
            this.displayPomadoro();
            setTimeout(this.startPomodoro, 1000);

        } 
        else {

          if(this.countBreak<breakInMnutes){
            var minutesLeftBreak = this.breakInMinutes - this.countBreak;
            currentTimerText = "Your have " + minutesLeftBreak + " Minutes Left in Break.";
            this.countBreak++;
            this.displayPomadoro();    
            setTimeout(this.startPomodoro, 1000);

        }
            else {
                this.currentTimerText=" Break Time is UP. ";
                this.displayPomadoro();
            }
        }
    },
    displayPomadoro: function(){
        var pomodoroHtmlElement = document.createElement('p');
        var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
        pomodoroHtmlElement.textContent=this.currentTimerText;
        outputDiv.appendChild(pomodoroHtmlElement);    
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine your issue is related to scoping issues of the `this` keyword when you're trying to run `setTimeout(this.startPomodoro, 1000);`. The scope of `this` will be the `startPomodoro()` method - you need the parent scope to be able to call that again.

Comment: setTimeout(this.startPomodoro.bind(this), 1000);

Comment: @epascarello Yes , setTimeout(this.startPomodoro.bind(this), 1000); is working, but It would be very helpful If , I can understand the explanation of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem with `this` not being what you think, when function was called from `setTimeout`. Try something like this:

```js
var pomodoroClock = {
  countPomadoro: 0,
  countBreak: 0,
  currentTimerText: '',

  startPomodoro: function() {
    var that = this;
    var pomadoroTimeInMinutes = document.getElementById('pomodoroInput').value;
    var breakInMinutes = document.getElementById('breakInput').value;
    if (this.countPomadoro < pomadoroTimeInMinutes) {
      var minutesLeftPomadoro = pomadoroTimeInMinutes - this.countPomadoro;
      that.currentTimerText = "Your have " + minutesLeftPomadoro + " Minutes Left.";
      that.countPomadoro++;
      that.displayPomadoro();
      setTimeout(function() { that.startPomodoro() }, 1000);
    } else {
      if (that.countBreak < breakInMinutes) {
        var minutesLeftBreak = that.breakInMinutes - that.countBreak;
        currentTimerText = "Your have " + minutesLeftBreak + " Minutes Left in Break.";
        that.countBreak++;
        that.displayPomadoro();
        setTimeout(function() { that.startPomodoro() }, 1000);
      } else {
        that.currentTimerText = " Break Time is UP. ";
        that.displayPomadoro();
      }
    }
  },
  displayPomadoro: function() {
    var pomodoroHtmlElement = document.createElement('p');
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
    pomodoroHtmlElement.textContent = this.currentTimerText;
    outputDiv.appendChild(pomodoroHtmlElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cold-md-12 text-center">
  <button>Set Pomodoro</button>
  <input id="pomodoroInput" type="number">
  <button>Set Break</button>
  <input id="breakInput" type="number">
</div>
<div class="cold-md-12 text-center"><br>
  <button onClick="pomodoroClock.startPomodoro()">Start Pomodoro</button>
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

PS. You also had a typo `breakInMnutes` instead of `breakInMinutes`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by moving away from jquery , and simply 
setting event handler on divs by wrapping each image inside one div using 
JavaScript. Below is the sample code.

```
//code

handler.divs.forEach(function(div){ 
                var img = document.getElementById(div);
                img.onclick = function(){
                    var id = parseInt(img.id,10);
                    userPattern.push(id);
                    handler.effect(id);
                    console.log(" div clicked " + id + " u p " + userPattern);
                    if(userPattern.indexOf(id) !== simonGame.PATTERN.indexOf(id)){
                        console.log(" if ");
                        handleWrongInput();
                    } else if(userPattern.length === simonGame.PATTERN.length){
                        setTimeout(function(){simonGame.patternGen({result:"success"})},1200);
                    }
                }

        });
console.log(" up " + userPattern + " SGP " + simonGame.PATTERN);
```